# Setting properties in the AUT from inside Squish

Tags: squish

is it possible to set certain properties in the AUT from inside Squish.

In my special case I try to resize a window by mouseDrag which unfortunately does not work.

As a workaround it would be ok for me to resize the window by setting its width-property to a new value...

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

found the answer with the help of Squish support:

via Qt's API:

```
obj1=waitForObject(":Address Book_MainWindow")
obj1.setFixedSize(200,200)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you've managed to work it out, but to further your answer slightly. From squish you can access all* properties and methods of the Qt objects you are dealing with.

The squishIDE provides two views to help with this, accessible by:

- Window -> Show View -> Methods.
- Window -> Show View -> Properties.

Any listed method can be called just like methods in python

```
obj = waitForObject(":objectWithMethod")
obj.MethodName(arguments)
```

However there are many pitfalls with this, the arguments passed often must be QObjects, and not Python objects, and the return values will also be QObjects. So sometimes they do not behave as expected in python.

There is also the general warning that directly manipulating your application somewhat invalidates your UI test, as you are no longer testing it from a user's point of view. However as a workaround it is sometimes required.

*in my experience there have been rare ocassions when you cannot.